# Cryptic D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain output

Tags: directx-11

My `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` call results in the following output to the Output Window (I'm using VS2017):

```
IGIESW PATH_TO_EXE found in whitelist: NOIGIWHW Game PATH_TO_EXE found in whitelist: NO
```

where `PATH_TO_EXE` is actual path to my .exe.

This doesn't seem to be causing any issues and everything runs as expected, but still, I'm curious about what this message means.

Comment: You might have happened to create a exe with the same name as another application that has some appcompat shim enabled.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with previewing a DirectShow capture. I'm facing a problem with the same error message which I've detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054832/geforce-experience-share-feature-generates-whitelist-errors-and-slows-performanc