# GeForce Experience share feature generates whitelist errors and slows performance

Tags: directshow, nvidia

I'm developing an application which is previewing video feeds from a capture card and/or a webcam. I've noticed a lot of errors in my console that look like:

```
IGIESW [path to my.exe] found in whitelist: NO 
IGIWHW Game [path to my.exe] found in whitelist: NO
```

These repeat each time I try to activate a preview window or switch the source feed I'm trying to preview. It actually takes a few seconds each time and it really kills the responsiveness of my application. I'm also seeing a similar slowdown in other applications which are previewing and switching between sources.

I have two nearly identical machines and I only see the errors on the machine with the NVIDIA graphics card; it doesn't happen on the machine using the built-in Intel HD graphics. This lead me to believe it was an NVIDIA setting and on a hunch I tried disabling the "Share" feature in GeForce Experience and that fixed the problem! I really need to use the screen capture capability to record my application so simply leaving it disabled isn't an option.

I searched online for information about IGIWHW and IGIESW but I really couldn't find much other than a few "my game won't work" type forum posts.

I don't see any reference to a whitelist in the Share settings nor in the online help for the NVIDIA control panel. I tried adding my path to the list of paths in the Games scanning settings but it didn't help. Does anyone know where this whitelist is setup? It's strange that even though the errors seem to indicate that my app isn't whitelisted it still works (just very slowly).

I have GeForce Experience 3.6.0.74 and driver 381.65 running on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no and there seems to be very little information to go on. Out of desperation I searched through the registry and I did find Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpResources\Registry\HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\OEM\WhiteList but I have no idea what I could do to the values in there to fix the problem. I also posted in the NVIDIA forums and I'd appreciate a bump there: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999112/share-feature-generates-whitelist-errors-and-slows-performance/

Comment: My issue was caused by invalid OpenGL textures, which I was actually able to fix (which is odd because the error doesn't indicate anything like this.) Not sure if that helps you at all though, sorry.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem recently with my own DirectX app as it attempts to generate its own second preview window - these errors appear in the output log unless I disable the NVIDIA overlay. It appears that NVIDIA only consults this whitelist when the app misbehaves, since this app is actually crashing on creating the preview window, while another app I have (that is clearly not whitelisted) works just fine and does not generate this warning.

Comment: Update: a very sharp person on the NVIDIA forums figured out that if you name your executable to Skype.exe the problem goes away! For a full list of filenames that work please see the thread: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999112/general-graphics-programming/share-feature-generates-whitelist-errors-and-slows-performance/post/5207073/.

Comment: Update: as of Geforce driver 388.71 and Geforce Experience 3.11.0.73 I'm no longer having this issue. I have no idea what changed in these versions that might have corrected it.